# How to Transform a accelerometer signal to wavelet?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, accelerometer, wavelet

I am solving a classification task using accelerometer gait data. I have tried time domain (mean, variance, skewness, ...) and frequency domain (amplitude, bandpower, energy, ...) features but getting a very low accuracy around (65%-70%) .

Sample accelerometer signal Y-axis
[image: sample accelerometer data]

Classifiers used so far: Random Forests and SVM.

Now
I want to use wavelet features but I have not worked before on Wavelets.
So I need help in:
 1. How to transform accelerometer signal to wavelet (matlab functions)?
 2. List of wavelet features that can be used for machine learning task?

Thanks

Comment: Are you splitting the data into a series of windowed frames?

Comment: Yes, i am using windows size of 50 frames